# filter a glob-like regex pattern in boto3

Tags: glob, boto3

Can I use boto3's filter tool for finding keys (technically sub-keys) in a bucket akin to files in a directory using glob?

I want to get a list of keys with a pattern like this `"key/**/<pattern>/**.gz"`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately not.  S3 provides no server-side support for filtering of results (other than by prefix and delimiter).

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [exrex](https://github.com/asciimoo/exrex) library to generate all strings based on a regex and pass that to boto3. This is a simple example but you can imagine something a bit more complicated:

For example:

```python
import exrex
import boto3
session = boto3.Session() # profile_name='xyz'
s3 = session.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('mybucketname')

prefixes = list(exrex.generate(r'api/v2/responses/2016-11-08/(2016-11-08T2[2-3]|2016-11-09)'))

objects = []
for prefix in prefixes:
    print(prefix, end=" ")
    current_objects = list(bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix))
    print(len(current_objects))
    objects += current_objects
```

This gives output:

```
api/v2/responses/2016-11-08/2016-11-08T22 1056
api/v2/responses/2016-11-08/2016-11-08T23 1056
api/v2/responses/2016-11-08/2016-11-09 24677
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by (ab)using the paginator and using `.gz` as the delimiter. Paginator will return the common prefixes of the keys (in this case everything including the `.gz` file extension not including the bucket name, i.e. the entire Key) and you can do some regex compare against those strings.

I am not guessing at what your `<pattern>` is here, and the regex I have provided is a bit rough and ready but essentially what you want is this.

```python
import boto3
import re

region = 'ap-southeast-2' ## <- YOUR REGION HERE
s3client = boto3.client('s3', region_name=region)

paginator = s3client.get_paginator('list_objects')

source_bucket = 'MY-BUCKET-NAME'
source_prefix = 'OPTIONAL-PREFIX/NESTED/'

pat = re.compile(r'key\/.+\/<pattern>\/.+.gz')

for result in paginator.paginate(Bucket=source_bucket, Prefix=source_prefix, Delimiter='.gz'):
    for prefixes in result.get('CommonPrefixes'):
        commonprefix = prefixes.get('Prefix')
        key_path = commonprefix.split('/')
        m = re.search(pat, key_path[2])
        if m is not None:
            print(commonprefix)
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a lib that can help you.

```bash
pip install s3fs
```

After install it, you can use glob-like pattern, like bellow.

```py
>>> from s3fs import S3FileSystem
>>> s3 = S3FileSystem()
>>> s3.glob('mybucket/some/prefix/any*file.*.gz')
['mybucket/some/prefix/any-file-in-s3.tar.gz']
```

See the complete [documentation here](https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).