# How to use regex to get a list of s3 objects using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to read objects from an S3 bucket and everything worked perfectly normal. Below is my working code.

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd

def get_s3_dataframe(object_name,schema):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')                                                                                                                         
    s3_bucket = 'some-bucket'                                                                      
    s3_prefix = f'/{object_name}/data/'                                   
                                                                                                                
    bucket = s3.Bucket(s3_bucket)                                                                               
    s3_data = None                                                                    
                                                                                                                
    for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=s3_prefix):                                                         
        //read-data
    
    return s3_data
```

Now the problem is that this works fine till the time I provide a complete object name as parameter to this function. My requirements have changed and now instead of passing one name, I need to pass an object name with regex so that it read data for all objects which confirm to the regex.

sample object name - `Test.%Server1%.%`. Did some digging online and came across the fact that s3 natively doesn't support object filtering on server side.

What can be the best performant way to achieve this ?

Comment: Within the `for` loop, you can add your own regex code to confirm whether the object Key matches the desired pattern. So, S3 will return the complete list, but you can filter it within your Python code.

Comment: You can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35442383/filter-a-glob-like-regex-pattern-in-boto3